# Is there somewhere to style a Furfrou in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'd like to transfer over my Furfrou (and other Pokemon) from XY, but I'm wondering if there's a place to restyle Furfrou's hair, like the hardressers in Lumiose?

Does an NPC offer these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find an NPC that will style Furfrou's hair in the Pokémon Fan Club in Slateport City.

[image: Furfrou styler in ORAS]